Архитектура базы данных мессенджера
Не очень понимаю, как хранить множественную информацию в бд, которая привязана к сильно менее множественной. Например, чат в мессенджере: у нас есть таблица чатов - id, юзеры, которые туда входят и тд. Но как хранить сообщения и их информацию? Логично создать таблицу сообщений и ее связать с таблицей чатов по id. Но чатов в тысячи раз меньше чем сообщений. Когда надо будет достать все сообщения из какого либо чата придется искать по всей таблице сообщений, что очень затратно по ресурсам и времени.
Ещё один вариант - это создавать таблицу сообщений для каждого чата, но мне кажется то что такой подход почти не используется, тк в тех ORM, которые я использую, такого функционала нет.
Также можно общую таблицу сообщений индексировать. Это уже более реалистичный вариант. Но не уверен, что лучший.
Подскажите, как лучше всего реализовать это максимально производительно в sql бд?

Главное, не хранить больше, чем нужно. Как правило, мессенджеры не хранят чаты пользователей. Каждые клиент чата сам хранит сообщения чата.

@rotabor - современные мессенджеры (ICQ, Telegramm) - хранят историю на сервере.Именно поэтому, кода Вы ставите чат на новое устройство - к Вам с сервера приезжают списки конактов и вся история сообщений. Друое дело - что для отображения используется локальная база -  в случае, когда используется "толстый клиент". а в случае веб-клиента - все делается на сервере

@S.H. Telegram хранит от полугода до года. Viber и WhatsApp точно не хранят чаты на серверах.

@rotabor в телеге есть апи даже для скачки сообщений. Было бы странно, если бы апи работало только когда другой клиент с историей онлайн

@tym32167 значит, Телеграм - очень стрёмный мессенджер.

Автор, ваша проблема не ясна. В реляционной бд есть индексы, потому если держать таблицу с сообщениями и делать выборку по чату и датам, при норм прописанных индексах не надо сканировать всю таблицу. При этом скорость работы подобного станет проблемой только когда у вас масштабы сопоставимые с тем же телеграмом, а если у вас нагрузка - пару запросов в секунду, то вам возможно обычной бд с лихвой хватит.

@rotabor имхо, они все должны хранить историю, иначе просто не пройдут сертификацию безопасников. Но это мое предположение конечно, я свечку не держу, но по умолчанию считаю что любой мессенджер в любой момент может слить все переписки куда захочет.

@rotabor WhatsApp уже тоже стал хранить

По идее сервер должен хранить сообщения сжатыми зашифрованными кусками и отдавать их (куски) при запросе с нового устройства чтобы сохранить целостность данных. Сервер не должен хранить чистые данные (хотя с новым законодательством я не уверен что не должен), по крайней мере не безопасно для конечного юзера. Единственный честный приватный и надежный вариант это передавать историю от одного клиента к другому, а серверу остается содержать в себе только медиа контент и общедоступную информацию. Все сообщения доступны на клиенте и должны оставаться только за ним.

Первым делом скажу, что учитывая ваши масштабы вам сойдёт БД практически любого формата, разве уж искусственно замедленная может тормозить)
Здесь же я просто делюсь своими уперевшимися в оптимизацию мыслями, так что если вам покажется что то неэффективным/непрактичным будет интересно пообщаться на эту тему в комментариях!
Как уже упоминали в комментарии к оригинальному вопросу:

Главное, не хранить больше, чем нужно.

Учитывая что у нас огромное количество сообщений хранение метаданных к каждой из них будет довольно неэффективно. По хорошему для максимального сжатия стоит их хранить с минимальным количеством метаданных, друг за дружкой, без какой либо лишней информации об их хранении.
Связанный список
Первым делом я подумал о простом связанном списке, записанном в файл "как есть". Условно:
0 [1.len] [1.data] [1.prevlen] [2.len] [2.data] ... [(n-1).len] [n.len] [n.data] [n.len] [eof]

где len - размер текущего блока данных и data - сами данные.
Таким образом мы сможем легко прыгать от одного сообщения до другого без каких либо лишних проблем как по связанному списку не читая и не храня в памяти весь объект (определённый набор данных).
Непрерывный поток данных с ссылками
Далее мне пришла в голову более простая версия - можно просто хранить все данные непрерывно, но в начале выделить массив фиксированного размера с ссылками на эти самые данные. Условно:
[n][1.offset][2.offset]...[n.offset][1.data][2.data]...[n.data]

Где offset - сдвиг позиции данных относительно начала объекта, а data - сами данные.
Таким образом мы сможем получить доступ к любому элементу данных за константное время имея на руках весь объект.

В случае если мы хотим отредактировать или удалить сообщение мы можем установить определённый флаг в data и после запихнуть туда же отредактированные данные или ссылку на новые данные если они туда не влезают (которые уже могут храниться в стандартном sql формате)
Далее можно просто поделить эти объекты (непрерывные блоки данных) на несколько участков по времени или (что более вероятно) по количеству. Условно начинать записывать в новый блок после 100 сообщений.
Каждый из этих объектов можно хранить в условной табличке или в виде файлов и надеятся, что ФС не умрёт)

В общем если подумать можно много что интересного надумать

Эта задача интересна, и, я уверен, она попадается на "архитектурных секциях" собеседований.
Есть два соображения:

понятно, что "сообщения" должны храниться в единой таблице (таблица Messages).

Вместе с каждм сообщением должны храниться еще три поля:
DateTime - время (видимо, в формате UTC)
AuthorId - идентификатор того, кто написал сообщение
ChatId - это Id того чата, в который было отправлено сообщение.
Из этой таблицы можно получить содержимое любого чата. Достаточно сделать выборку по ChatId.

Но, может оказаться, что делать такую выборку по кокретному чату по всей таблице Messages - слишком долго.
Тогда можно сделать дополнительную таблицу, в которой будут храниться только сообщения текущего чата.

В терминологии DB это называется "денормализацией", а в современных DB есть еще понятие materialized view, предназначенных для этой же цели - быстрая выборка данных.
При этом, каждое новое сообщение должно добавляться в два места:

в "общую таблицу" Messages (для всех сообщений) и

в таблицу сообщений конкретного чата



Подскажите а зачем дублировать запись в общую таблицу сообщений? Почему не хватит оставить сообщения в таблице конкретного чата?

@MoloF - я думаю, это уже детли, о которых я не могу уверенно судить. Тот способ, который я кратко написал в ответе - хорошо своей "необязательностью": хотим - создаём отдельную таблицу для определенного ("суперпопулярного") чата, не хотим - не создаём. То есть, Messages - это некий "первичный истояник данных". Можно пойти и по другому пути.

Кстати, а не наврал ли я в ответе? в том смысле, что когда я пишу "При этом, каждое новое сообщение должно добавляться в два места" - не будет ли это враньём в случае использования materialized view? Попробую проверить...
